# Trouble loading static files from Digital Ocean Spaces in my Django project

Tags: django, video, static, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

During the development of my project I could display video files through my templates like this:

```
<video width="200" controls>
    <source src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.video }}' type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

`MEDIA_URL` was directed to a `media` folder in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Now I am in production and using Digital Ocean Spaces, my static and media files are both served by `STATIC_URL`. When a user creates a post that contains a video file I can see it uploaded in Spaces, I can also view it through the Django admin. But I cannot find the code I need to make it playable on the site anymore. I just see a grey box telling me the file is not supported. I have tried changing `{{ MEDIA_URL}}` to `{{ STATIC_URL }}`, I have also tried `<source src='{% static "post.video" %}' type='video/mp4'` but neither of these have worked. I cannot find the answer to this anywhere online. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: You have to configure Nginx like so

location /static/ {
        root YOUR_PROJECT_PATH;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root YOUR_PROJECT_PATH;;
    }

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. I am a real beginner to all this server stuff. Can you please explain what you mean by configure Nginx?

Comment: As you were deploying to digitalocean, what server engine are you using? I am assuming you deployed on a droplet?

Comment: Yes I did. I used Ubuntu/Gunicorn/Nginx but I am no expert in this area. I followed a tutorial to guide me.

Comment: Fyi, my images, fonts, CSS etc. is uploading already from my Spaces folder. It is only the video files that I cannot get to work

Comment: Does this mean your videos are in another folders apart from the css and images?

Comment: I have separate sub-folders for css, images, videos etc. but they are all contained within the same main folder.

Comment: So this means your media and static are in the same main folder. In that case, you should be using STATIC_URL. When you inspect element in your browser to check the path of STATIC_URL, what shows up? Have you also done /manage.py collectstatic?

Comment: Yes I have done collectstatic. When I inspect the element it shows up correctly as if it is working fine. I have also set the content type by managing metadata on the Spaces control panel. Still nothing...

Comment: Can you print your console and do a screenshot? Do you see any errors? Maybe video rendering errors?

Comment: Finally it works. I was missing `url` off the end of my template tag. Didn't need that during development but apparently it's necessary in production. Cheers so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the template to read:

```
<video width="200" controls>
    <source src='{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ post.video.url }}' type='video/mp4'>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```